# How many non-homeomorphic separable metrizable topological spaces are there?

Tags: general-topology

I am working in ZFC.

By the theorem of Urysohn, any separable metrizable topological space can be embedded as a subset of $I^\infty$, the Hilbert cube.

Therefore we get an upper bound on the number of non-homeomorphic separable metrizable topological spaces, there is at most $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ of them.

**Question**: How many different separable metrizable topological spaces are there?

Note that separability is equivalent to second-countability in a metric space, so that we can ask the more general:

**Question$^*$**: How many different metrizable topological spaces of weight $\leq \aleph$ are there?

Weight, as usual, is the least cardinality of all of bases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{X}=\{X\subseteq\Bbb R:\Bbb Q\subseteq X\}$; clearly $|\mathscr{X}|=2^{2^\omega}$ (or $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$, if you prefer). Let $X\in\mathscr{X}$; $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $X$, so any embedding $e$ of $X$ into $\Bbb R$ is completely determined by $e\upharpoonright\Bbb Q$. There are only $\left(2^\omega\right)^\omega=2^\omega$ functions from $\Bbb Q$ into $\Bbb R$, so there are at most $2^\omega$ members of $\mathscr{X}$ homeomorphic to $X$. Thus, $\mathscr{X}$ must have $2^{2^\omega}$ homeomorphism classes, and $\Bbb R$ must have $2^{2^\omega}$ pairwise non-homeomorphic subspaces, all of which are clearly separable and metrizable.

On the other hand, if a space $X$ is separable and metrizable, it’s homeomorphic to a subspace of the Hilbert cube $H$. $|H|=2^\omega$, so $H$ has $2^{2^\omega}$ subsets, and there are therefore exactly $2^{2^\omega}$ pairwise non-homeomorphic separable, metrizable spaces.